# How to access attributes from a method?

Tags: python

I have a python code where I created a class, the defined attributes in `__init__()` are given from a dictionary. I would like to access these attributes from other functions. The code is a little bit long so I created the following example where I find and error once I call `a.printatt()`:

```
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Code:

```
dic = {'name': 'john', 'age': '12', 'job': 'student'}

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        var = {}
        for index, key in enumerate(dic):
            var[key] = getattr(self, key, dic[key])
            print(var[key])

    def printatt(self):
        print(var['name'])

a = MyClass()
a.printatt()
```

Comment: If you want to tie the variable to the object, use self.var instead of var.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `self.var`?

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your problem:

```
dic = {'name': 'john', 'age': '12', 'job': 'student'}
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = {}
        for index, key in enumerate(dic):
            self.var[key] = getattr(self, key, dic[key])
            print(self.var[key])
    def printatt(self):
        print(self.var['name'])
a = MyClass()
a.printatt()
```

This gives me the following output:

```
john
12
student
john
```

Comment: Yeah, Roland beat me to the answer. Just remember that if you want to store or access saved values within a class, you need the 'self' identifier. Otherwise the variable is discarded. Also note the parentheses when a = MyClass() is declared. For me it is easier to keep things straight if I just use parentheses both when I define the class and declare instances of the class. >> class MyClass():

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot sir !